# Unable to Change Apple ID and password

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-id

I have tried repeatedly to change my Apple ID and password without success. I have followed all of the directions trying both my emails and asked for new passwords----no luck whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

If you've followed all the correct processes for changing your Apple ID, including verifying your email address is correct and looking in your spam/junk folder, then your only option is to contact Apple directly.

Go to [Apple's Support page](https://support.apple.com/contact) and click on `Talk to us`.  Initiate a chat session, that's the fastest way to get this resolved.